Are the marginals of these two joint distributions the same?
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$ be random variables. Let $\mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}$ be a regular conditional distribution. Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $\mu_1^X$ and $\mu_2^X$ their pushforward measures under $X$, respectively.
Now we can construct distribution $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ on the joint space $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ via
$$ \nu_i(A\times B) = \int_A \mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X=x}(B) \, d\mu_i^X, \quad i=1,2  $$
My question is now if those two distributions $\nu_1, \nu_2$ on the joint space have the same $Y$-marginal?
I.e., is $\nu_1^Y=\nu_1(\mathcal{X}\times B)=\nu_2(\mathcal{X}\times B)=\nu_2^Y$ ?
If so, how can I show this?

Under which condition? Counter-examples are obvious.

@Xi'an I would be happy to see a counter example!

maybe that would help me to understand what conditions I wanto to impose

If $\mu_1^X$ corresponds to a $N(0,1)$ and $\mu_2^X$ to a $N(10,1)$, while the conditional of $Y$ given $X$ is a $N(X,1)$, the marginals differ.

Thanks a lot. Are there conditions or assumptions under which the two marginals would be the same?

The question is too vague, I am afraid, to be answered by anything but the definition for the two marginals to be equal.

Okay thank you and sorry for too broad question. Would it change anything if the two maringals were absolutely continuous w.r.t. some common refrence meausre?

No, it does not make a difference. Having the same marginal on $Y$ for two different distributions on $X$ indicates that $Y$ depends weakly (or not at all) on $X$.
